# How to create json object?

Tags: java

I have string

```
 {"comp1.a":1,comp1.b":"2","comp1.c.aa":3,"comp1.c.bb":"4"}
```

The name of the field will always will be with '.' and if there is another level it will be with another '.'

I want that the result of the input will be :

```
{"comp1":{"a":1,"b":"2","c":{"aa":3,"bb":"4"}}}
```

How I can do it without string actions?

Comment: This would require some custom parsing - have you tried anything? Show what attempt you have made to parse this.

Comment: Do you really have to parse it in Java? In JavaScript it would be much simpler.

Comment: I need it in java and it is not homework.I didn't know if to start with split of the string or there is generic way to do it

Comment: there are libraries like Gson that convert json strings to java objects, but i think they might have a problem with this naming convention, you can try and see.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you mean by 'string actions'.  You could parse the input `String` into `JsonObject`s but as you'd still have to split the field names so you may as well just parse the original `String`.

Here's how I did it:

First I removed the `{` and `}` and split based on `,`:

```
String[] tokens = "{\"comp1.a\":1,comp1.b\":\"2\",\"comp1.c.aa\":3,\"comp1.c.bb\":\"4\"}".replaceAll("\\{|\\}", "").split(",");
```

Then I wrote a recursive parse method that takes each token and builds a graph using `java.util.Map`:

```
private void parse(Map graph, String token)
{
  int index = token.indexOf(".");

  if (index > -1)
  {
    String name = token.substring(0, index).replaceAll("\"", "");
    String remainder = token.substring(index + 1, token.length());

    Map children = (Map)graph.get(name);
    if (children == null)
    {
      children = new HashMap();
      graph.put(name, children);
    }

    parse(children, remainder);
  }
  else
  {
    String[] nameValuePair = token.split(":");
    graph.put(nameValuePair[0].replaceAll("\"", ""), nameValuePair[1]);
  }
}
```

If this method finds a `.` in the token it creates another level in the graph and recurses, if not, it just adds the value to the graph.

Next I wrote a method that will convert this graph back to a valid JSON string:

```
private void toJson(StringBuilder jsonBuilder, Map graph)
{
  jsonBuilder.append("{");

  for (Object key : graph.keySet())
  {
    jsonBuilder.append("\"").append(key).append("\"");

    Object value = graph.get(key);

    if (value instanceof Map)
    {
      toJson(jsonBuilder.append(":"), (Map)value);
      jsonBuilder.append("}");
    }
    else
    {
      jsonBuilder.append(":").append(value).append(",");
    }
  }

  jsonBuilder.replace(jsonBuilder.length() - 1, jsonBuilder.length(), "}");
}
```

You could obviously replace use of a `StringBuilder` in this code with the Java JSON API of your choosing, the parse method already did the hard work.

Putting it all together like this:

```
String[] tokens = "{\"comp1.a\":1,comp1.b\":\"2\",\"comp1.c.aa\":3,\"comp1.c.bb\":\"4\"}".replaceAll("\\{|\\}", "").split(",");

Map graph = new HashMap();
for (String token : tokens)
{
  parse(graph, token);
}

StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
toJson(jsonBuilder, graph);

System.out.println(jsonBuilder.toString());
```

I get the output:

```
{"comp1":{"a":1,"b":"2","c":{"aa":3,"bb":"4"}}}
```